# Writing, not uploading, to S3 with boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, python-2.6

Is there a way to directly write to a file in S3 rather than uploading a completed file?  I'm aware of the various `set_contents_from_` methods, which work well when I want to upload a completed file.  I'm looking for a way to write directly to an S3 key as data comes in.

I see in [the documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.open_write) that there is mention of an `open_write` method for `Key` objects, but it is specifically called out as not implemented.  I'd rather not go with something cheesy like the following:

```
def WriteToS3(file_name,data):
  current_data = Key.get_contents_as_string(file_name)
  new_data = current_data + data
  Key.set_contents_from_string(new_data)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As  it is based on REST, it is not possible to only update one part of the content.

Comment: S3 does not offer a streaming interface so there really isn't any way to do what you are proposing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using S3 multipart upload feature to archive this. You can upload each part sequentially, and complete the upload. See more details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html